# Mission Control freezes. Restarting Dock doesn't help

Tags: mojave, dock, mission-control, multi-touch

I use standard settings to open Mission Control in *MacOS Mojave 10.14.4* on *MacBook Pro*.

Normally swipe up with 3 fingers move all windows into Mission Control mode and I can switch to any available window.

After some time period of time (may be several days) Mission Control stops working.

Swipe up gesture freezes my Mac for about one minute (only mouse cursor can be moved, no other changes on screen). After one minute (without any error messages) I can use apps again, Dock works as well, Cmd-Tab works to switch between applications, but Mission Control doesn't appear in any way. I cannot start it neither by using Shift-Up (standard shortcut), nor from Spotlight.

There are a lot of 'solutions' in internet, where everybody advise to restart the Dock. I have restarted Dock several times, both using Activity Monitor, or Terminal. Dock process Id gets updated (it seems to be restarting), however it doesn't solve my problem.

Only *workaround* I found so far, is to **reboot my Mac**. However, I'd like to avoid any rebooting if possible.

Comment: I am experiencing the exact same thing. It's incredibly frustrating.

Comment: Exactly the same problem here on my Mojave 10.14.4 MacBook Pro... has been occurring a couple of times a day for the last two or three weeks. I'd love to be in the loop if anything about this problem is discovered... Rebooting once I'm unfrozen is all that works for me so far too.

Comment: This is driving me insane. It is sometimes also happens when when other apps are opening or switching windows. I cant see a exact pattern of when it occurs but there seems to be some correlation with number of apps open, and maybe wifi connection quality (i notice the problem more often on an ios hotspot than a regular wifi router). I'm restarting my mac 4/5 times per day to try and get any work done.

Comment: Well, Ask Different won't let me answer, but here's the best solution I've found. I can get it to fix itself by unhooking my external monitor and then sleeping the computer. When I wake it up again and can use Mission Control again without problems on the laptop monitor I hook my external up again and it works without any problems. I've had it work 3 times now and while it's not a solution to prevent it it get's me working again without restarting.

Comment: That is odd, you have to have more privileges to comment than to answer.

Comment: Same exact issue here with Mojave and 2018 MBP. It seems to happen after my MBP goes to sleep with the external monitor plugged in.  After waking the computer has this problem or is completely frozen. Ugh... my 2013 MBP had issues with external monitors too. Was hoping they fixed this in Mojave and 2018 MBP.

Comment: For what it's worth, I sent my 2017 MBP in for display repairs and since it's come back I haven't had this problem any more, even after restoring old system state from Time Machine. Maybe a hardware problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution/workaround so far. 
Thanks to Shaded, who posted a comment with this workaround.

## TL;DR

To unfreeze Mission Control without restarting MacBook

- Disconnect external monitor
- Close MacBook and let it sleep (optionally: Click "Apple" menu -> Sleep)
- Open MacBook - now everything work again (monitor can be connected as well)

## Details

It seems, that the problem is caused by some configuration issues when MacBook works with an external monitor.
After disconnecting the monitor, a display driver(?) is being reset(?), Mission Control doesn't freeze anymore, and monitor can be connected again.

Important note: The MacBook should go to standby mode (sleep) after disconnecting monitor. There is a 'Sleep' item in the Mac system menu. I didn't test if it works. I have just closed a lid and went to drink a coffee.

Another note: At the moment of freezing - CPU load is 100%. MacBook is getting hot and turns cooling fans at maximum speed.

Comment: There's a sleep option in the... system? apple? whatever that top left menu that's indicated with the apple logo is called... I'd try just clicking that and see if it can get it fixed up quicker. Thanks for crediting me in the answer :D

Comment: @Shaded - Thanks for hint. I have changed the description.

Comment: Didn't work for me. I can't even get the second display back up. Looks like a reboot is inevitable now.